# Nearest relevant airport search not returning expected airport

Tags: amadeus

I'm trying to use Amadeus' [Airport Nearest Relevant API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/203/api-doc/9/api-docs-and-example/10007) and I'm running in to a weird case. Given the following parameters

```
latitude: 45.366431
longitude: -75.7955389
radius: 100
```

I would expect to get the nearest airport, Ottawa International, but am instead getting OGS--an airport in New York state, ~86km away as compared to Ottawa's 10km. Ottawa doesn't even show up in those search results, in fact--it exclusively lists NY state airports, none in Canada let alone in Ottawa. This seems weird.

One thing to note is that I'm using the sandbox API, not the production API. Would that affect anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the test environment offers only a subset of our data (you can find [here](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/hackathon-starter#datasets) the list of supported countries for Airport Nearest Relevant). If you want to access to all the data you will need to move to production.

This list of supported countries/cities/airports per API will be soon published on the portal.

Comment: Ah, good to know; I was looking for a doc explaining the differences between sandbox/prod actually, I didn't know about that repo. If possible, having those differences documented alongside the actual API might be nice.

Comment: @moberemk you are totally right, we are working to expose it on the portal in a much better way. The GitHub page is a temporary solution.