# some of the countries do not seem to be supported?

Tags: amadeus

I am trying to understand if I can use Amadeus' API to work with airports and flights in France.

I am using [amadeus-node](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-node).

This returns 0 result when I add the `countryCode` (ie. `result.data` is empty)

```
    const airports = await amadeus.referenceData.locations.get({
      keyword: keyword,
      countryCode: "FR", // once added, results are gone
      subType: "AIRPORT",
    });
```

When I remove the country code, it works fine and returns results from the US, Spain and Germany for example.

This other request returns only airports in Spain, while there are in Southern France (eg. MPL)

```
const airports = await amadeus.referenceData.locations.airports.get({
  // next to Montpellier's airport https://goo.gl/maps/XfWBtsu6ZeF9SoDNA
  longitude: 3.93, 
  latitude: 43.58,
});
```

Did I miss something in the documentation? Is this available for France? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Well I think [this post from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034979/nearest-relevant-airport-search-not-returning-expected-airport?rq=1) actually answers my question.

It's because not all data is available outside of production. I will most probably get the results I expect once I use the prod environment!